# Add DropDown list between two rows of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview control on my aspx page and I am inserting the data in it and its working fine but Now I want to Add a dropdownlist between Each row alternatively For example:
let suppose this is My Inserted Row :

```
Name   Age   Country
```

Now after inserting this row I want a row to be automatically added just having only a dropdown list Nothing else..Is it Possible ? Can Any one help ?

Here is my code adding Rows in GridView

```
 DataTable dt_amount = new DataTable();
        if (validateAmountLevelAdding())
        {
            dt_amount.Columns.Add("Sr.No");
            dt_amount.Columns.Add("User");
            dt_amount.Columns.Add("Min_Amount");
            dt_amount.Columns.Add("Max_Amount");
            dt_amount.Columns.Add("Level");
            dt_amount.Columns.Add("emp_code");
            dt_amount.Columns.Add("job_id");
            int NextSerail = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow gvRow2 in GV_AMOUNT_EMP.Rows)
            {
                dt_amount.Rows.Add();
                dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][0] = gvRow2.Cells[0].Text;//serial no
                dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][1] = gvRow2.Cells[1].Text;//User
                dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][2] = gvRow2.Cells[2].Text;//Minimum Amount
                dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][3] = gvRow2.Cells[3].Text;//Maximum Amount
                dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][4] = gvRow2.Cells[4].Text;//level
                dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][5] = gvRow2.Cells[5].Text;//empCode
                dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][6] = gvRow2.Cells[6].Text;//JobId
                NextSerail = Convert.ToInt32(gvRow2.Cells[0].Text)+1;
            }
            if(NextSerail==0)
            {
                NextSerail = 1;
            }
            dt_amount.Rows.Add();
            dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][0] = NextSerail;
            dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][1] = DDL_EmpForAmount.SelectedItem;
            dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][2] = txt_min_amount.Text.ToString();
            dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][3] = txt_max_amount.Text.ToString();
            dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][4] = DDL_LEVELS_AMOUNT.SelectedValue;
            dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][5] = DDL_EmpForAmount.SelectedValue;
            dt_amount.Rows[dt_amount.Rows.Count - 1][6] = DDL_Jobs.SelectedValue;

            Session["levels_amount"] = dt_amount;
            GV_AMOUNT_EMP.DataSource = Session["levels_amount"] as DataTable;
            GV_AMOUNT_EMP.DataBind();

        }
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Okay Edited..You can see Now

Comment: You can add rows in row_databound event,

Comment: Can you please Elaborate it with code?